# java web application integrating with active directory on OC4J server

Tags: java, windows, servlets, active-directory, oc4j

I would like to make a servlet (application deployed on OC4J ) which will allow to enter users logged in domain (Active Directory) without any prompt for login and password. Is it possible to retrive in servlet : user name via getRemoteUser or getUserPrincipal methods without authentication form? Or other way of doing that what I need?

Comment: you want to automatically login a Windows user into your web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure what OC4J calls 'Windows Native Authentication', as described in the [OC4J Security Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12524_01/web.1013/e12514/configwna.htm). It's a bit more work than just calling a particular function - you have to configure Active Directory and OC4J first.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with the Kerberos protocol.  Here is a good explanation of how it might work in a servlet/jsp environment.

http://webmoli.com/2009/08/29/single-sign-on-in-java-platform/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an open source library, http://spnego.sourceforge.net, that will do exactly what you want.

It only has examples for Tomcat, JBoss, and Glassfish.

But it's implemented as a servlet filter so it should work on any servlet container.